# Going from one textfield to another

Tags: swift

I have four separated `UITexField`s,  each of one character, for verification purposes

They are shownas below :

( - - - - )

I need a way such that, when the user types in one text field it will go to the next textfield without the need to click on the other textfield.

Or, if there is another way to achieve this feature please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking all textfield in view, just take only 1 textfield (in code only - not in view hierarchy) that will take whole code from user. and take 4 buttons on screen - who's titles will be textfield's characters based on index. So by that way you can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Good Question Boss
  I have a solution for your question.
try this... 
Note* As per your requirement you operate text field from textFieldDidChange method...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet var text1 : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var text2 : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var text3 : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var text4 : UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   //TAG FOR IDENTITY
    text1.tag = 1
    text2.tag = 2
    text3.tag = 3
    text4.tag = 4

    text1.becomeFirstResponder()

    text1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    text2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    text3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    text4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)


}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ sender : UITextField){

    if sender.tag == 1{
        text1.resignFirstResponder()
        text2.becomeFirstResponder()

    }else if sender.tag == 2{
        text2.resignFirstResponder()
        text3.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if sender.tag == 3{
        text3.resignFirstResponder()
        text4.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if sender.tag == 4{
        text4.resignFirstResponder()
    }else{
        print("Done")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you could use 4 text fields and move to the next one on editingChanged which would be written like so :

```
@IBOutlet weak var code1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var code2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var code3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var code4: UITextField!


func addTargets() {
    code1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    code2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    code3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    code4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
}


@objc func editingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    switch (sender) {
        case code1:
            code2.becomeFirstResponder()
        case code2:
            code3.becomeFirstResponder()
        case code3:
            code4.becomeFirstResponder()
        default:

            // your code input would be done here, you could handle for example code verification

            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First keep your textFields globally accessible within the UIViewController class.

Make sure your UIViewController conforms to the delegate UITextFieldDelegate.

Then for each textField, in your UIViewController, set the delegate:

```
textField.delegate = self
```

For the following code, I consider the below 4 text fields as an example. The user enters the phone number from left to right. The textField names, in order, are ext, areaCode, middleThree, finalFour.

[image: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/spontit/id1448318683]

**Moving to the next field when the user presses the return key**

```
// Return text field upon pressing return
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.ext {
        self.areaCode?.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        self.areaCode?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.areaCode {
        self.middleThree?.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        self.middleThree?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.middleThree {
        self.finalFour?.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        self.finalFour?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.finalFour {
        self.finalFour?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

**Moving to the next field once a character count is completed (e.g. once a user types in 4 characters in a textield, go to the next one.**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString: String) -> Bool {

    var characterCountLimit = 0;

    switch textField {
    case self.ext:
        characterCountLimit = 3
    case self.areaCode:
        characterCountLimit = 3
    case self.middleThree:
        characterCountLimit = 3
    case self.finalFour:
        characterCountLimit = 4
    default:
        characterCountLimit = 1000
    }

    // Determine how many characters in the string after the change happens.
    let startingLength = textField.text?.count ?? 0
    let lengthToAdd = replacementString.count
    let lengthToReplace = range.length

    // This might be called when the user presses backspace, but the count is has reached the limit. Thus, we have to determine the new length.

    let newLength = startingLength + lengthToAdd - lengthToReplace
    // If the user did not press backspace, but continued typing, move to the next field. Take the most recently typed character and enter it as text in the new field and remove it from the old field.
    if newLength > characterCountLimit {
        switch textField {
        case self.ext:
            self.areaCode.text = String(describing: (replacementString.last)!)
            self.areaCode?.becomeFirstResponder()
        case self.areaCode:
            self.middleThree.text = String(describing: (replacementString.last)!)
            self.middleThree?.becomeFirstResponder()
        case self.middleThree:
            self.finalFour.text = String(describing: (replacementString.last)!)
            self.finalFour?.becomeFirstResponder()
        case self.finalFour:
            break
            // Do nothing. This is handled by the editing change delegate method.
        default:
            break
        }
    } else if replacementString.isEmpty && range.lowerBound == 0 && range.upperBound == 1 {
        // If the user is pressing backspace and you want to return to the previous field
        switch textField {
        case self.finalFour:
            self.finalFour.text = ""
            self.middleThree?.becomeFirstResponder()
        case self.middleThree:
            self.middleThree.text = ""
            self.areaCode?.becomeFirstResponder()
        case self.areaCode:
            self.areaCode.text = ""
            self.ext?.becomeFirstResponder()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return newLength <= characterCountLimit
}
```